# RegEx that detects space between numbers but space between commas are ok

Tags: regex, angularjs

I am using angularjs and curently have the following REGEX

```
ng-pattern = "/^[0-9,\b\s]+$/"
```

This regex works to a degree although I am unable to find how to alter it to detect white space between numbers, but at the same time allow white space between commas.

ie

```
123                     // is ok
123,  345,   5453       // is ok
123   345,   5453       // is not ok
123,   345,   5453,     // is not ok
,123,   345,   5453     // is not ok
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what about `123,   345,   5453,` ? I take this as not ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:\d+(?:, *|))*\d+$
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mL2aL8/2)

Comment: you absolute legend! Will set as corrent answer!

Comment: I just noticed that this regex doesnt consider a comma at the end. Could this regex be updated to pass error if user has comma at the end without a following number?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:\d+,\s*)+\d+$
```

http://regex101.com/r/xE2sQ3/1

```
123,  345,   5453    // OK
123   345,   5453
123,  345,   5453    // OK
123,  345   5453,
```

Comment: you were right Fede, I didnt consider the other options. How could I modify this to allow just numbers like   "123" without any commas.

Comment: @AntonHughes the \d means only number, but if you just want 123 you can change the `\d` by `[123]`. If you don't want the comman then remove it. You can have something like: `^(?:[123]+\s+)+[123]+$`

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression

```
^\d{1,3}(,\s*\d\d\d)*$
```

Matches

- start-of-text, followed by
- a group of 1-3 digits, followed by
- zero or more groups, each consisting of

  - a comma, followed by
  - optional whitespace, followed by
  - a group of 3 digits
    -followed by end-of-text

Which is to say...any number written in the conventional group-delimited form using commas as the group delimiter and allowing trailing whitespace following the commas:

```
1
12
123
1,234
12, 123,456
```

All match, but things like

```
123456
123,4
1 234
```

If you wanted to make the group separators optional, it's an easy modification:

```
^\d{1,3}((,\s*)?\d\d\d)*$
```

This will also match numbers like

```
12345
12, 3456
```

Etc.